# iPhone App rejection under guideline 22.2

Tags: ios, app-store

I submit my iPhone App to Apple a week ago.Few hours ago, Apple has rejected my app saying**`Apps that contain false, fraudulent or misleading representations will be rejected`**

Also following is the detail of resolution centre:

```
We found that your app, and/or its metadata, contains content that could be 
misleading to users, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
Specifically we noticed the app's concept references being able to calculate a
users Blood Alcohol content, which is misleading and not appropriate for the app store.
```

Now my question is What are all the things that I have to take care of under Apple guideline 22.2: `Apps that contain false, fraudulent or misleading representations will be rejected`.
Any help would be appreciated. Thnx in advance.

Comment: I think the title of the rule is self explanatory.  Just don't make any false, fraudulent or misleading claims.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue here is that the only way to correctly calculate blood alcohol level is using a breath test or blood test.  I assume your app is using body mass or something similar to **estimate** a blood alcohol level.

I assume Apple have taken exception to the fact that you are claiming an estimate is accurate.  You may be able to reword your app description to make it clear that it is an estimate.  However, I wouldn't be surprised if Apple still rejects the app. Particularly given the statement above: "being able to **calculate a
users Blood Alcohol content**, which is misleading and **not appropriate for the app store.**"

Are you prepared for the response from users when they use your app and decide they are fit to drive and then get busted or injure/kill someone?  Apple may feel the risk of being sued is too great. Personally, I'd steer clear of the potential legal issues around such an app.

**Update**: It appears similar apps already exist in the App Store so you may be able to get the app accepted by changing the wording in the description. However, I get over 100 results when I search for blood alcohol so Apple may still reject it on those grounds.

Comment: Thnx mttrb, I will update my description then try to resubmit..hope that goes well.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the wording if your feature "calculate a USERS blood alcohol content" it could almost seem like you're saying you can detect this (via hardware - breathing into the phone maybe) when really I am assuming you input a load of parameters for a person and collection of drinks and work out an amount if alcohol.

Try stating "calculate a persons blood alcohol level" instead if a "users" level.

For me that is the issue - a wording problem. Not a content problem.